# How to stream audio to a specific output device?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, audio, audio-streaming

Have been struggling with finding a way to stream audio, from a file or web, to a specific output device, not just the default one. Tried using `mciSendString` and while the [open command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/open) does accept a device id/filename I haven't found a way to make use of it, am not even sure if this is what I am looking for or not, but considering it says `... or the filename of the device driver` am guessing yes(?), but correct me if I am wrong, and this isn't a `specify your output device` type parameter.

If it is the correct thing then how do you enumerate the installed device drivers, have looked into the  `IMMDevice` interface because it seamed like it could have the file names stored in the registry, but non of the output device registry keys had a `driver filename` type value entry, or at least I haven't found one.

So my question is, how would you go about streaming audio to a specific output device, it doesn't have to be done through `mciSendString`, that's just something I looked into as it's one of the most talked about function when it comes to playing audio.

Note: please do **not** recommend me 3rd party libraries like NAudio, the reason I am asking this question is not get recommendations for libraries, otherwise I would have already used one and would have never written this, have just seen a lot of answers be like: `Use {LibName}, it has what you want` or something along those lines.

In case what's written is odd or incorrectly worded in places, basically this is what the end goal should be:

```
Installed Output Devices:
 - Output1
 - Output2
 - Output3

Method For Playing:
  //will play x.mp3 through output device 1
  PlayAudio(output: "Output1", mp3File: "x.mp3");

  //will play x.mp3 through output device 2
  PlayAudio(output: "Output2", mp3File: "x.mp3");

  //will play x.mp3 through output device 3
  PlayAudio(output: "Output3", mp3File: "x.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for this API：[mciSendCommand()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757160(v%3Dvs.85))

> To set the WaveAudio device (soundcard) used by the Multimedia
>   Control, you must use the mciSendCommand API. The Multimedia Control
>   does not directly provide a method to let you set the device used for
>   playing or recording.

- Call `mciSendCommand()` with `MCI_SET` & `MCI_WAVE_SET_PARMS`
  setting wOutput to the desired playback device's ID.
- Then get `IDDevice` for `mciSendCommand(`) via
  `mciGetDeviceID("waveaudio")`

Its not 100% clear what `wOutput` wants, its probably the same ID as returned by `waveOutGetDevCaps()`

**I am just a porter.**

Please refer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320137/11128312

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10968887/11128312